# in javascript ,apart from parameter passing in call and apply is there is any other difference where only call will work and apply can not?

Tags: javascript, concept

i want to know the concept for call and apply uses,
Is there any execution wise difference between them.
why java script introduced call over apply?

where and when we can use call and apply in javascript?

Answer (score 1):

`call` is like `bind`, except that the function is immediatly executed.

`apply` is like `call`, except you pass the arguments to the function as an array.

```
myFunc.call(this, arg1, arg2, ..., argn);
```

is equivalent to

```
myFunc.bind(this, arg1, arg2, ..., argn)();
```

which is equivalent to

```
myFunc.apply(this, [arg1, arg2, ..., argn]);
```